# Marshalling Objective-C to C# with Unity, Mono, and P/Invoke

Tags: objective-c, mono, pinvoke, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call Unity C# script from the Objective-C side.  Functions with void parameters work.  Functions with string parameters work if the script on the other side is Javascript.

Functions with string parameters crash if the script on the other side is C#.  The crash is a BAD_EXEC.

I'm fairly sure I'm not correctly marshalling parameters correctly.  There really isn't too much documentation about this on the web.

I've read Embedding Mono and I've looked at the really old examples on Github.

http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/samples/embed

Types and functions are declared as such:

```
typedef void* MonoDomain;
typedef void* MonoAssembly;
typedef void* MonoImage;
typedef void* MonoClass;
typedef void* MonoObject;
typedef void* MonoMethodDesc;
typedef void* MonoMethod;
typedef void* MonoString;
typedef int   gboolean;

MonoDomain*     mono_domain_get();
MonoAssembly*   mono_domain_assembly_open(MonoDomain* domain, const char *assemblyName);
MonoImage*      mono_assembly_get_image(MonoAssembly* assembly);
MonoMethodDesc* mono_method_desc_new(const char* methodString, gboolean useNamespace);
MonoMethodDesc* mono_method_desc_free(MonoMethodDesc* desc);
MonoMethod*     mono_method_desc_search_in_image(MonoMethodDesc* methodDesc, MonoImage* image);
MonoObject*     mono_runtime_invoke(MonoMethod* method, void* obj, void** params, MonoObject** exc);
MonoClass*      mono_class_from_name (MonoImage *image, const char* name_space, const char *name);
MonoString*     mono_string_new(MonoDomain* domain, const char* str);
```

Then variables are declared:

```
@interface UnityObject : NSObject
{
    MonoDomain*     domain;
    NSString*       assemblyPath;
    MonoAssembly*   monoAssembly;
    MonoImage*      monoImage;
    MonoMethodDesc* runChallengeDesc;
    MonoMethod*     runChallengeMethod;
}
@end
```

And then in init:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        assemblyPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"];
        domain = mono_domain_get();
        monoAssembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, assemblyPath.UTF8String);
        monoImage = mono_assembly_get_image(monoAssembly);
        runChallengeDesc = mono_method_desc_new("Marshal:RunChallenge(string)", FALSE);
        runChallengeMethod = mono_method_desc_search_in_image(runChallengeDesc, monoImage);
        mono_method_desc_free(runChallengeDesc);
    }

    return self;
}
```

The above all works as expected.

Then the method is called:

```
NSString *msg = @"Some message string";
MonoString *str = mono_string_new(domain, msg.UTF8String);
void *args[1];
args[0] = &str;
if (runChallengeMethod)
    mono_runtime_invoke(runChallengeMethod, NULL, args, NULL);
```

I'm fairly sure I'm not correctly marshalling parameters correctly.  The crash is a BAD_EXEC.

Comment: The crash is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, you mean? This line looks awfully funny if that's ObjC code: `mono_runtime_invoke = (method, NULL, args, NULL);` That assigns `NULL` to some variable called `mono_runtime_invoke`. Looks like it's supposed to be a function call. Please copy-paste your real code into the question.

Comment: I don't see what `void *args[1]` is supposed to be, either.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: I used a similar code before to call a function from obj-c to unity, and it worked. Now I needed this code again, and i'm getting BAD_EXEC. MonoMethod *runChallengeMethod is null. Any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to elaborate a little more on the code you posted. With the code you posted, assuming that the "..." is implemented correctly, you are executing a *static* method with 1 parameter that is undefined.

You at least need to do this instead:

```
void* args[1];

args[0] = mono_string_new(domain, msg.UTF8String);

mono_runtime_invoke (method, NULL, args, NULL);
```

I can only guess that the transcription from your real code to this question was done poorly as almost 0 of the code you posted is valid.

The code at http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono#Creating_objects shows how to pass Mono  Strings when they are not out or by ref.

Comment: This is not correct because args[0] needs to be a pointer to a MonoString*.  You can verify this by looking at line 205 here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/samples/embed/test-invoke.c#L205

Comment: @ParveenKaler: Read the comment just before that line: "Now let's see how to handle methods that take by ref arguments" - If your string parameter isn't ref/out, then args[0] is just a MonoString*, not a pointer to it.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Pretty sure you just solved why the program crashes. I hadn't looked at question since the OP updated it with real code.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you can see how to set args on the page referenced in the Question. http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono#Creating_objects